In my fastapi application, how do I make async SQLAlchemy play well with Pydantic when my SQLAlchemy models have relationships?
I am building a fastapi CRUD application that uses Async SQLAlchemy. Of-course it uses Pydantic since fastapi is in the picture. Here's a gist of my problem
SQLALchemyModels/

foo.py

    class Foo(Base):

        id_: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, priamry_key=True)
        bar_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey="bar.id_")
        bar: Mapped["Bar"] = relationship("Bar", back_populates="foo")

bar.py

    class Bar(Foo):

        id_: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        foo_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey="foo.id_")
        foo: Mapped["Bar"] = relationship("Foo", back_populates="bar")

PydanticSchemas/

foo.py

    class Foo(BaseModel):

        id_:int = Field(...)
        bar_id: int = Field(...)
        bar: Bar = Field(None)

bar.py

    class Bar(BaseModel):

        id_:int = Field(...)
        foo_id: int = Field(...)
        foo: Foo = Field(None)


If I query for Foo SQLAlchemy mapped row in the database, I want to validate it using Foo Pydantic BaseModel. I have tried the following approaches to load the bar relationship in Foo
SQLAlchemy selectinload/ selectload/subqueryload
Since these loading strategies emit a query which only loads bar object when called, I tried to create a pydantic field validator to load bar.
class Foo(BaseModel):

    id_: int = Field(...)
    bar_id: int = Field(...)
    bar: Bar = Field(None)

    @field_validator("bar", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_bar(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, SQLALchemy.orm.Query):
            v.all()
        return v

This validation obviously fails since I am using async SQLAlchemy and I cannot await v.all() call in synchronous context.

SQLAlchemy joinedload

Joinedload assigns creative names to fields in joined table and so it becomes almost impossible to pydantically validate them
I have now leaning towards removing relationships and corresponding fields from my SQLAlchemy models and Pydantic classes respectively. I can then load Foo object in my path operation function and then use its id to query (SELECT IN query) bar object. This seems overly complicated. Is there a better way?


AdaptedConnection.run_async(). look docs.



You can use Pydantic models as Pydantic fields (for example to validate user, user's messages, user's likes on profile), you can use .options(selectinload(User.tweets)) for example, and then get tweets by user.tweets


I'm not sure why you need to perform the validation manually at all? You already have the relationships, and when you load them through joinedload, they'll still be available under the relevant attributes (since SQLAlchemy maps between the aliases used in the query and the attrbute name). Use from_attributes=True in your model config, and you should be able to do everything automagically from your SQLAlchemy orm instance?

If you want automatically load bar when you query foo, and don't use lazy loa, you could use:
foo: Mapped["Bar"] = relationship("Foo", back_populates="bar", lazy="selectin")

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html
